# iOS Quartz Changing stroke color

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am new to iOS and am doing this as a learning experience. I got most of this code from a tutorial and its working but I wanted to add more stroke colors. My code begins with a default stroke in UIColor greenColor, but I have two buttons labeled "Red" and "Blue" that should change the stroke color to Red or Blue when pressed. I want to press Red, then start drawing and have that stroke come out red, etc. like in MS Paint. I've confirmed my UIButtons are linked up correctly. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**DrawView.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DrawView : UIImageView
- (void)changeOption:(NSString *)withOption;
@end
```

**DrawView.m:**

```
#import "DrawView.h"
@interface DrawView()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL fingerMoved;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint lastPoint;
@end

@implementation DrawView

CGFloat red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0, width = 5.0;
@synthesize fingerMoved = _fingerMoved;
@synthesize lastPoint = _lastPoint;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)changeOption:(NSString *)withOption
{
    if ([withOption isEqualToString:@"Black"]) {
        red = 0.0; green = 0.0; blue = 0.0; width = 5.0;
    }else if ([withOption isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {
        red = 1.0; green = 0.0; blue = 0.0; width = 5.0;
    }else if ([withOption isEqualToString:@"Blue"]) {
        red = 0.0; green = 0.0; blue = 1.0; width = 5.0;
    }else if ([withOption isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {
        red = 0.0; green = 1.0; blue = 0.0; width = 5.0;
    }else if ([withOption isEqualToString:@"Brown"]) {
        red = 0.4; green = 0.0; blue = 0.0; width = 5.0;
    }else if ([withOption isEqualToString:@"Orange"]) {
        red = 1.0; green = 0.6; blue = 0.0; width = 5.0;
    }else if ([withOption isEqualToString:@"Yellow"]) {
        red = 1.0; green = 1.0; blue = 0.0; width = 5.0;
    }else if ([withOption isEqualToString:@"Purple"]) {
        red = 0.5; green = 0.0; blue = 1.0; width = 5.0;
    }else if ([withOption isEqualToString:@"Eraser"]) {
        red = 1.0; green = 1.0; blue = 1.0; width = 13.0;
    }else if ([withOption isEqualToString:@"Clear"]) {
        self.image = nil;
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.fingerMoved = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        self.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    self.lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    self.lastPoint = CGPointMake(self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y - 20);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.fingerMoved = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), width);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        self.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    if (!self.fingerMoved) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
        [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), width);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Setting the stroke color part looks correct to me. Just to confirm, right now when you draw it only draws in green?

Comment: The method `chooseColor` is called with a color name as `NSString`.  Are you sure that the method is being called with a valid color name?

Comment: This looks pretty good, please post the code that your buttons call so that we can check that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It was a silly mistake in my Controller code. This above code changes stroke color now, but what I don't get is the Clear part in **changeOption**. I am doing the same thing to clear the image just like in the code below it, with the double tap to clear, but it doesn't do anything. Do I need to redraw to screen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Silly mistake in some other code. Fixed now.